# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ihelploginapi\index.php on line 5

Tags: php, json

This code was working 2 days before, but now i am getting an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ihelploginapi\index.php on line 4.

Somebody please help me out.

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    $tag = $obj->{'tag'};
?>
```

Comment: can you `var_dump($obj)` on the line after json_decode and post the results?

Comment: Error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$tag' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ihelploginapi\index.php on line ..

Comment: code :<?php
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj = json_decode($json,TRUE);
 var_dump($obj)
 $tag = $obj->{'tag'};
 

if ($tag != '') {
    // Get tag
    $tag = $obj->{'tag'};

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` does not give you an object.  It gives you an array.
You want to access it as such:

`$tag = $obj['tag'];`

or to re-write the var names more accurately

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$php_array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$tag = $php_array['tag'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the related line use :

```
$tag = $obj['tag'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `json_decode()` tells it to convert JSON objects to PHP associative arrays, not PHP objects. So you need to use `$obj['tag']` instead of `$obj->tag`. Or change the decode line to

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```